# Gnuplot round values for xtics label

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a resulting plot that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBZIA.png

and as you can see, there are a lot of values and so the xtics labels are unreadable.

Is it possible to only display "round values" like 100000, 110000, 150000 etc and not all the values between them ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `xtics`.

For example:

```
set xtics 10000
```

This sets xtics in increments of 10000.

You can also specify the begin and end value:

```
set xtics  <start>, <incr>, <end>
```

(Using the end value is optional.)

In `gnuplot` use the command `help set xtics` to learn more.